# Mouseover effects for social network icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation

Hey so I have written some code out in jQuery, but it seems to violate DRY. I'm not too familiar with JavaScript or jQuery, so I was just asking for some advice on how to optimize this code:

```
$("#twitter").rotate({
  bind:
  {
    mouseover : function() {
    $(this).rotate({animateTo:360});

    $("#twitter").fadeTo(function() { 
        $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeTo(); });
        $(this).attr("src", "images/logos/Twitter-Color.png");
    });
  },
  mouseout : function() {
    $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
    $("#twitter").fadeTo(function() { 
        $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeTo(); }); 
        $(this).attr("src", "images/logos/Twitter-White.png");
    });
  }
  }
});

$("#linkedin").rotate({
  bind:
  {
    mouseover : function() {
    $(this).rotate({animateTo:360});

    $("#linkedin").fadeTo(function() { 
        $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeTo(); });
        $(this).attr("src", "images/logos/Linkedin-Color.png");
    });
  },
  mouseout : function() {
    $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
    $("#linkedin").fadeTo(function() { 
        $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeTo(); }); 
        $(this).attr("src", "images/logos/Linkedin-White.png");
    });
  }
  }
});
$("#facebook").rotate({
  bind:
  {
    mouseover : function() {
    $(this).rotate({animateTo:360});

    $("#facebook").fadeTo(function() { 
        $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeTo(); });
        $(this).attr("src", "images/logos/Facebook-Color.png");
    });
  },
  mouseout : function() {
    $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
    $("#facebook").fadeTo(function() { 
        $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeTo(); }); 
        $(this).attr("src", "images/logos/Facebook-White.png");
    });
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is the code you posted here indented as intended?

Answer (score 1):

#### Styling and readability

Your indentation is incorrect. This makes it harder to read, and makes people assume that "mouseout" belongs to a different Object that it actually does.

Whitespace is not always consistent (e.g. `$(this).rotate({animateTo:360});` versus other uses of Objects.

#### DRY

As you correctly noted, this code repeats itself quite a bit.

The code seems to only differ in id and logo name. You have various options:

- You create a function that sets this. I am not entirely sure what you would name it, but something like `setRotationEffects( id, logoName );` might do the trick.
- You can use named functions for `mouseout` and `mouseover`. This will leave you with a basic boilerplate for each id:

  ```
  $("#linkedin").rotate({
    bind:
    {
      mouseover : whatEverYouCallIt,
      mouseout  : whatEverOtherThingYouCallIt
    }
  });
  ```

  This might be more optimal if you expect to have other similar constructs with different effects.

Similarly:

- The id in the mouseover and mouseout handler is not needed. In the handler you can use `$(this)` instead. This leaves you with only the name of the logo.

  - You can consider pulling this name from the existing logo. After all, the logo was set to a particular name in the first place. This makes all these identical.
  - You can use an anonymous function containing a function call with parameters (`function() { doTheThings( id, logoName ); }`.

*Note: It might be just me, but I link "optimize" to "performance", and DRY has nothing to do with performance. We use DRY to make maintenance easier, not to make code outperform "WET" code.*

Comment: Nice answer. "Optimization" is broader than just performance, though ;-)